# How to update Database BackgroundMode when Local Notification are arrive?

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, uilocalnotification

I have a Local Notification which fire every minute. Its fire date & other data are taking into the local database. I am used the notification delegate method for notification which gives me notification Active & Background mode.

When Notification fire then update sqlite database every notification (every minute). when notification  fire it’s update sqlite database In Application Active State. That’s state working done.

**my code like**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    // I recieved a notification
    if (notification) {
        [Update DataBase Method];   
     }

}
```

But my problem is when Application goes Background Mode then Database not Update only Notification Received.

How can I update my database its goes in Background mode (or any state) at every notification fire?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [apple site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) that explain the task in background/suspend mode..

> (Recommended) Register for any notifications that report system changes your app needs. When an app is suspended, the system queues key notifications and delivers them when the app resumes execution. Apps should use these notifications to make a smooth transition back to execution. For more information, see “Processing Queued Notifications at Wakeup Time.”

So if app is queuing the notification than you can access this notification data when your app opens next time.
So what you should have to do is that ..

1. When your app start check that if there is any notification.
2. If there is than do the database operation according to the data of the notification

Do the Database update task from `applicationDidBecomeActive` method. `applicationDidBecomeActive` method will called whenever your app become active.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive.
    //If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    NSLog(@"Dilip applicationDidBecomeActive");
}
```

I think this will do the work...